# T-SQL Case Where Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that allows the user to select some options in the UI. They can either choose to search by specific users or view all data regardless of the user.

My current `WHERE` clause looks like the following:

```
WHERE e.mgrQID IN (SELECT QID FROM @temp)
  AND i.isRetired = 0
  AND ym.year IS NOT NULL
  AND ym.month IS NOT NULL
```

Now this works fine when searching by user which is how I had it initially. I am trying to add in an option to bypass the user piece.

This is the sudo logic:

```
CASE 
   WHEN @viewType = 'leader' 
      THEN e.mgrQID IN (SELECT QID FROM @temp) 
   ELSE WHEN @viewType = 'all' 
       DONT INCLUDE THIS USER PART 
END
```

In short, I am trying to wrap the first line of the `WHERE` clause in a CASE statement and only have it run when the variable being passed called `@viewType` is equal to `leader`.

Comment: Try this article on the topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: try 
where (@viewtype <> 'leader' OR e.mgrQID IN (SELECT QID FROM @temp) )
and

Comment: `(@viewtype <> 'leader' OR e.mgrQID IN (SELECT QID FROM @temp) )` doesn't help. both parts will be executed. The bullet-proof solution: `if @viewtype = 'leader'` one query `else` another query.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) and not a statement - you can return one of several possible, atomic, single values - but you **cannot** use `CASE` to selectively execute code snippets or control the flow of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do some preprocessing, if it's leaders you want, put them in a temp table, if it's not leaders, put everyone in the temp table instead

```
DECLARE @viewType VARCHAR(100)
SET @viewType = 'leader'

DECLARE @tblIdsIWant TABLE
(
    QID INT
)
IF (@viewType = 'leader')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tblIdsIWant
        SELECT QID FROM @temp  --get leaders only
END
ELSE  --@viewType = 'leader'
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @tblIdsIWant
        SELECT QID FROM dbo.yourTable  --get everything, including leaders
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.yourOtherTable 
WHERE e.mgrQID IN (SELECT QID from @tblIdsIWant)
```

Comment: While I thought about doing that, I wasn't sure if adding 50k+ people to a temp table would be efficient for something like this.

Comment: Are there 50K+ leaders or is everyone else 50k+?

Answer (score 0):

That's an `OR` isn't it?

```
WHERE (@viewType = 'all' or exists (SELECT 1 FROM @temp t where t.QID = e.mgrQID))
  AND i.isRetired = 0
  AND ym.year IS NOT NULL
  AND ym.month IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm simplifying it to much but i'd split the queries

Declare @viewType VARCHAR(100)

```
            set @viewType = 'leader'



            if @viewType = 'leader'

            begin

            SELECT 

            *
 FROM    TableName

             WHERE e.mgrQID IN (SELECT QID FROM @temp)
                                            AND i.isRetired = 0
                                            AND ym.year IS NOT NULL
                                            AND ym.month IS NOT NULL

  else

                            if @viewType = 'All'
                            begin

                            Select *

                            from Tablename
                            WHERE
                                            i.isRetired = 0
                                            AND ym.year IS NOT NULL
                                            AND ym.month IS NOT NULL

                            end
```